# A question about the General Renewal-Reward Process (the rate of a person's average happy days)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, renewal-processes

> Suppose a person’s mood changes periodically. The chances of the period being 2 or 4 days are equal and do not affect each other. Suppose the happiness index $h$ in a period is a semicircular curve with the midpoint of the interval as the center.

(a) Draw a sample of happiness index. (b) If $h$ is greater than 3/4, we call him happy. After a long time of observation, what rate of a person’s average happy days is?

[image: a]

I know $E[R_{n}]=E[min\{X,y\}]=\int_{x=0}^{y}Pr\{X>x\}dx$ and $\frac{E[R_{n}]}{\overline{X}}=\frac{1}{\overline{X}}\int_{x=0}^{y}Pr\{X>x\}dx~~WP1$. Obviously, $Pr\{Mean of period width\}=Pr\{\overline{X}\}=2*0.5+4*0.5=3$.

But I don't know how to calculate the value of $\int_{x=0}^{y}Pr\{X>x\}dx$.

Comment: Your sketch is correct.  On average half the circles are each size, so you just need to compute what fraction of the time out of your $6$ days the happiness is greater than $3/4$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. For the sample in (a), the calculation process you said is correct. My main confusion is how to calculate the ratio when time $t$ tends to a large number.

Comment: The rate is the time he is happy divided by the total time.  Because the two periods are equally probable, the long term rate is the same as you got for one of each.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand, thank you very much for your help.